# C Error: Initialization From Incompatible Pointer Type

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list

To start off, the goal with my program is to create my own malloc using the buddy allocation scheme. However, when I go to compile my code, I get the initialization from incompatible pointer type error. I am confused on what exactly this means and how I can fix it. Here is a short snippet of the function where this error is occurring:

```
node *fList[26] = {NULL};

void *divider(int index, int baseCase) {

    node *temporary = fList[index + 1]; 

    int size = ((1 << (index + 6)) / 2);
    node *toSplit =(char *)temporary + size; //where error occurs

    if(temporary->next != NULL) {
        fList[index+1] = temporary->next;
        temporary->next= NULL;
        fList[index+1]->previous = NULL;
    }
    else{
        fList[index+1]=NULL;
    }   

    temporary->next = toSplit;
    toSplit->previous = temporary;

    if(fList[index] != NULL){
        toSplit->next = fList[index];
        fList[index]->previous=toSplit;
    }
    else{
        toSplit->next = NULL;
    }

    fList[index] = temporary;
    temporary->previous=NULL;

    temporary->header = index+5;
    toSplit->header = index+5;


    if(fList[index]->header == baseCase+5){
        fList[index]->header |=128;
        void *tmp = fList[index];
        fList[index]=fList[index]->next;
        if(fList[index]!=NULL)
        {
            fList[index]->previous=NULL;    
        }
        return tmp;
    }
    else{
        divider(index-1,baseCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the full text of the error, which should highlight the line on which it occurs

Answer (score 1):

Error pretty much says it: you have cast `temporary` to be a different type of pointer than the variable `node` that you are trying to assign it to.

As for the *incompatability* part, there are typically rules for where structs can go in memory (the address has to be a multiple of usually 4 or 8), but `char`s aren't so restricted, and so you can have a `char` in a location where a `node` cannot be.

As for fixing it: cast it to the proper type, and make sure you are generating a valid address for your `node`.